# PYTHON: relational data between classes in OOP and how to use them the right way

Tags: python, class, inheritance, reference

i´m new to OOP and trying to get the right programming style. Currently i´m trying to work with three classes. One Parent- and Child-Class and a third class. The data between the classes should be connected. I know concepts of 'relational databases', but i´m not shure if i need some kind of secondary key in one class, to connect the other one in a flexible way.

Should i work with dictionaries instead, when i don´t want to integrate an external database?

Please have a closer look @ my comments in the code.

```
#Inheritance Person -> Customer
class Person:
    def __init__(self, person_id, firstname):
        self.person_id = person_id
        self.firstname = firstname
        # ...

class Customer(Person):
    def __init__(self, person_id, firstname, customer_level):
        super().__init__(person_id, firstname)               
        self.customer_level = customer_level
        # ...

    def get_customer_level(self):
        return self.customer_level

class BillFormular():
    def __init__(self, bill_id, customer_id, is_paid=False):
        self.bill_id = bill_id
        # currently i store the customer_id (as some kind of secondary key for 
        # the person_id in the inhereting BillFormular(Person)-Class, as i don´t  
        # have a relational database. Is that a good way?
        self.customer_id = customer_id          
        self.is_paid = is_paid
        # ...

    def print_bill(self):
        # the Argument 'judith' works, if i want to connect the other classes methods
        # But how to make it more flexible, e. g. by using the stored 'customer_id' 
        # in the BillFormular(Person)-Class and the 'person_id' in the Person-Class
    
        print(f'Your Status from external class: {Customer.get_customer_level(judith)}')

judith = Customer(22, 'Judith', 3)
bill42 = BillFormular(42, 22)
bill42.print_bill()
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not an expert in Python, so let's get that out of the way.
But, you don't need a 'key' here, like with databases. What you use here is the reference of the object, so you can also access the object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Python, so let's get that out of the way.

**But**, you don't need a 'key' here, like with databases. What you use here is the reference of the object, so you can also access the object.

So you would do it like this in the programming:

```
judith = Customer(22, 'Judith', 3)
bill42 = BillFormular(judith, 22)
```

Now you can access judith in bill42.

To give you an understanding of how this roughly works.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, person_id, firstname):
        self.person_id = person_id
        self.firstname = firstname
```

You have your class person here. The data that the class has (persond_id and firstname) need memory.

(how exactly this works is not interesting for now, because it might be a bit confusing at the beginning)

***The following picture is highly simplified and should only serve for understanding***

[image]

With the following line you have now created an Object Person. This must be saved to memory.

```
judith = Customer(22, 'Judith', 3)
```

As you can see in the picture above, judith was saved in address 15 to 17. In these memory cells (15-17) the self data (person_id and firstname) are stored. Python takes care of the exact location for you.

And you can do the handing over and everything around it simply by handing over to judith.